# Draw Circle Canvas instead of Rect fabric.js

Tags: canvas, draw, geometry, fabricjs

I want to draw canvas in Circle, as currently my canvas is creating in rectangle and all the objects are drawing inside, I want to make the area in circle and than all the objects can be drawn inside the circle. can any one have the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to collapse all 4 borders of your canvas into a circle with:

```
#yourCanvasID { border-radius:50%; }
```

After that you are in charge of drawing your shapes only inside the circular canvas.